# Get datas from TXT to a matrix

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have a homework to make a file like this, License plate, date, time, speed
like: AAA-111, 2019.01.01, 12:12, 50
I have to read these into the program and check if how many cars went there at the same date, and how much % went over a speed which given by the user, then to make a file "speeding" which contain the punishment, like 50-60 100 dollar, and to check if how many cars got punished, and to write it to a file by license plate, date, and the amount to pay.
I'm new to C, and I dont know what can I do when there is strings and integers in a file.
(Actually I'm a vehicle engineer, but it's just a stuffing course which we have to do, the teached teached nothing, we have to give in this homework to get a rating)

I have tried a method which stores the file char by char ( I think) but because then I have to see it by rows and columns, a matrix would be better. But if it is possible without it, that is good too.

Comment: You should share your code to show your efforts.

Comment: You are basically reading a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file here.  Use one of the CSV routines off the internet.  Google showed several options.

Answer (score 0):

first you should use `strucs` to store each fields of a line from your file as `char *` attribues.

then when you have your structs, you can go on with a function that takes a line and returns a pointer to your struct:

```
struct ticket_t *get_ticket(char *line);
```

Then you should figure how to read a file line by line with `getline(3)` you should have a bit of code [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) for this.

I suggest you find the number of line the file has and then create an array of `struct ticket_t*` of the correct length to ease the code (memory management).

As for the other parts of you assigment you should be ok with what I told you here.

Some documentation: [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), [fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html), [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)